# Como deixar fonte responsiva?

Tags: html, css

Qual a maneira de fazer com que o tamanho do texto seja responsivo e se adapte a tamanhos de ecrã diferentes?

Tentei usando unidades `em` mas não adiantou.

Já tentei usando Media querys:

EX: `@media(max-width:768px){font-size:1.5em}`

Ja tentei do método target/context= resultado.

EX: Meu h2 do meu slide tem 40px então peguei os 40 e dividir por 16 (40/16 = 2.5 em)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54624/discussion-on-question-by-gilmar-santos-como-deixar-fonte-responsiva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a unidade de medida "rem",
ela usa como base a fonte raiz da página ou seja da tag html que é sempre 16px.
isso evita ter que fazer cálculos com diferentes contextos.

Answer (score 5):

Um pouco sobre tamanhos de fonte:

**Ems** (em)

É escalável uma unidade que é utilizada em meios documento da web . Um em é igual ao font-size atual, por exemplo, se o tamanho da fonte do documento é 12pt , 1em é igual a 12pt . Ems são escaláveis ​​na natureza, assim 2em seria igual 24pt , .5em seria igual 6pt , etc.

**Pixels** (px)

Os pixels são unidades que são utilizados em meios de tela de tamanho fixo (isto é, para ser lida no ecrã do computador). Um pixel é igual a um ponto na tela do computador (a menor divisão da resolução do seu ecrã). Muitos web designers usam unidades de pixel em documentos da web , a fim de produzir uma representação pixel-perfeito de seu site como ele é processado no navegador. Um problema com a unidade de pixels é que ele não escala para cima para leitores com deficiências visuais ou para baixo para ajustar dispositivos móveis.

**Points** (pt)

Os pontos são tradicionalmente utilizados em meios de impressão (tudo o que é para ser impresso em papel , etc.). Um ponto é igual a 1/72 de polegada. Pontos são bem como pixels , na medida em que são unidades de tamanho fixo e não pode ser dimensionado em tamanho.

**Percent** (%)

A unidade cento é muito parecido com a unidade "em", salvo algumas diferenças fundamentais. Em primeiro lugar, o font-size atual é igual a 100% (ou seja, 12pt = 100%) . Enquanto estiver usando o aparelho por cento, o texto permanece totalmente escalável para dispositivos móveis e para a acessibilidade.

Fonte: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Em resumo use o % que será responsivo. Veja o exemplo:

```css
h1{
  font-size: 100%;
}

h2{
  font-size: 50%;
}

h3{
  font-size: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Teste 100%</h1>
<h2>Teste 50%</h2>
<h3>Teste 25%</h3>
```